# Why Shudras are not allowed to have wealth?

Tags: caste-system, manu-smriti

Manu Smriti 10.129

"*No collection of wealth must be made by a Sudra, even though he be able (to do it); for a Sudra who has acquired wealth, gives pain to Brahmanas.*"

Comment: Brahmanas created most of the rules in early hindu society, so they made most of them in favour of the creamy cast(I don't believe in such cast system).Brahmanas other wise little more white coloured human beings at that time misused their knowledge and prevented acquiring knowledge and wealth by others especially the dark skin coloured people.

Comment: Brahmanas feared rising of others will diminish their dominance in the society.

Comment: Most of the religious scriptures that gives importance to Brahmanas are written by them no doubt about that, now we can see the time has changed a lot now the playing field is equal.

Comment: Shudras are ones who endowed with **ignorance & low intellect** . Ignorant mind with low intellect, unable to discriminate between right & wrong, when given power is more dangerous to itself than to the others. Because under power, it is driven with ego, hatred, enviousness, lust, dishonesty which falls it down to the **lower births of insects & animals**. Such restriction was made not out of polishing ego of upper castes but to save them to commit sin. Hindu social structure was based on ensuring to uplift souls both in this life **as well as in the next life.**

Comment: This statement in fact is a care for Shudras otherwise who cares what they attain after death? Shudras materially improving themselves but not spiritually, surely won't bring a good birth after death.

Comment: @Rahulkr, while it is true some brahmins misused their power to subjugate other varnas, the rule-book (dharma-shastras) themselves are not to be blamed. Just because there is headache, do you cut off the head? Nowadays, only few people can even claim to be brahmins because most people don't follow vedic practices (sandhya, agnihotra etc.) and behave like shudras only. But don't ridicule smritis for that. If some people don't follow rules of a game, ridicule those players only, not the rules.

Comment: Even Brahmanas prevented learning rights of other people, how they can get know good and bad. I remember one incident, one of indias president "KR NARAYANAN" was from a lower caste, he learned well so he got the knowledge.

Comment: To know about good and bad one should be educated, in early days Brahmanas prevented education to lower caste.

Comment: @Rahulkr who said education is denied for Shudras and others?

Comment: @Hindu clear by the Practice of not allowing lower cast people access to town, schools, water etc. Prior to 1947( and it continued different forms after that btw) Education is a privilege that only wealthy can afford. Lower casts, as they were denied access to even water, are systematically deprived of any education that the 3 Varnas receive.

Answer (score 4):

[Here's](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc201871.html) the explanation given by Medhatithi in his commentary on the Manu Smriti:

> ‘Even though he is able’—by means of agriculture and such acts,—wealth shall not be amassed by the Śūdra. In support of this the Author adds an argument in the form of a declamatory statement—‘Having acquired wealth the Śūdra harasses the Brāhmaṇas.’ “What is the harassment caused to Brāhmaṇas?” Becoming very rich, they would make the Brāhmaṇas accept gifts from themselves, and the accepting of gifts from the Śūdra has been forbidden for them; hence becoming a party to their doing what is forbidden, he would incur sin.  The danger of incurring such sin however could not apply to the case of one who goes on fulfilling all that is prescribed for him. Hence the ‘harassment’ of the Brāhmaṇa that is meant is only this that he would no longer serve them.

So the problem is that by acquiring wealth he may be tempted to stop performing his duty of serving Brahmanas and other members of the first three castes.  And so he's forbidden from acquiring wealth in order to prevent this temptation.

However, if a low-caste person violates this and acquires wealth anyway, he should use this wealth to support members of the first three castes, as described in [this chapter](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe02/sbe0274.htm) of the Gautama Dharma Sutras:

> And a man of higher caste (who is his master and has fallen into distress must be maintained) by him.  **His hoard shall serve this purpose.**

Comment: The common goal of a Hindu in life as follows:
1-Dharma, 2-Artha(wealth or money), 3-Kama 4-Moksha.
So, as per this,Shudras can have wealth.

Comment: Another verse in Manusmriti says Brahmins won't stay where the king are from Shudra caste. How can a Shudra become king without wealth?

Comment: @VenkatachalamSeetha, it says Brahmins SHOULDN'T stay where shudras are kings.. but today, 99% 'kings' (or PMs or Presidents) are shudras, so no choice.

Comment: @VenkatachalamSeetha Manu Smriti verse 4.61 isn't saying that they're allowed to be kings.  They're not allowed to be kings, so the Manu Smriti is saying that if there is an evil country where they are kings, then Brahmanas should avoid such a place.

Comment: @ram Vedanta Desikan says in one of his works that Prapannas should live in a place where the four castes are well-established, and so he tells Prapannas to live in South India rather than North India.  I often joke that if Vedanta Desikan was living today, he would tell Prapannas go to Mars :-)

Comment: @Ajay What about it?  That doesn't contradict what I said in my answer.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan. https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/11/17/19

Comment: Sir Sudras cant earn wealth or property/Really?This was ever implemented? If say I am a Crafstmen,I earn money, I go and give all of it to Bramhanas?Nowhere it happened in history sir! Everyone is human and everyone has right to earn wealth. Please reply @KeshavSrinivasan Sir.